# Disable some physics effects

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am new here and as well in gazebo environment, I need some help from you guys!

What I need to implement right now is a moving platform in Gazebo. I did the model (a simple square) and wrote a plugin which assign a constant vertical speed by the SetLinearVelocity method. This platform will be used as a landing target for a quadcopter, hence I an not interested in simulating its dynamics. I just need a moving landing spot!

I tried to land on it with a robot but the platform, at the moment of touchdown, starts spinning.

To fix that, I just set the relative pose (orientation) to zero and  the problem disappears. Another issue arises, every simulation step i set the linear velocity right? Well when the robot touches the platform, the square just gets lower as if it is suffering from the robot weight.

Is there a simple way to disable those physics effects? I just need a square to which i can assign the position/velocity through a plugin and that's it.

Thanks in advance

Andrea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14975/disable-some-physics-effects/) by [andrea.nisti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2948/andrea.nisti/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think that disabling some physics effects could be tricky, because you want contact between the platform and the quadcopter.

You could try making a prismatic joint between the platform and the world and control that joint (maybe with `physics::JointController`) rather than setting velocity:

```
  <joint name = "world_joint" type="prismatic">
    <parent>world</parent>
    <child>platform_link_name</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
    </axis>
  </joint>
```

This way the platform movement is more constrained.

**UPDATE (alternative):**

An alternative just occurred to me. You can set your platform as a [static](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=model#model_static) model (i.e. it doesn't respond to the dynamics engine but does collide with other objects) and use `SetWorldPose` to change its position at every world iteration. You could modify the random velocity plugin from [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_random_velocity&cat=) tutorial to do that.

Regarding your question about time, check that tutorial for `_info.simTime`, which is the time in simulation.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrea.nisti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2948/andrea.nisti/) on 2016-12-12**:
Hello,

sorry for my late answer but I was not at work. Thanks for your advice, as soon as I can i will try your update solution; what does exactly mean a "static" object inside the gazebo framework?

A second question: since I am pretty new and I did not see any tutorial on this, how does gazebo manages time? How can I get a simulated time in second/milli etc.. ? Thanks a lot!

Andrea Nisticò

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-12-12**:
Moved this to a comment, since it is not an answer ;)

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-12-12**:
I edited the question to answer your comments, hope that helps :)

**Comment by [andrea.nisti](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2948/andrea.nisti/) on 2016-12-12**:
Thanks a lot,I finally have a moving platform (oscillating with a frequency) in gazebo and looks fantastic! I really appreciate that ;) I guess you will hear from me again soon , Thanks again ;)